# OpenGL array textures not rendering at all

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

I'm currently working to convert a project from using a texture atlas to an array texture, but for the life of me I can't get it working.

Some notes about my environment:

- I'm using OpenGL 3.3 core context with GLSL version 3.30
- The textures are all 128x128 and rendered perfectly fine when using an atlas (barring the edge artifacts which convinced me to switch)

Problems I believe I've ruled out:

- Resolution issues - 128x128, being a power of two, should be fine
- Texture loading (it works perfectly as it did before)
- Incomplete textures (mipmap issues) - I've gone through the common issues regarding mipmaps and I don't believe OpenGL should be expecting them

Here's my code for creating the array texture:

```java
public void createTextureArray() {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    int handle = glGenTextures();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, handle);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, Texture.SIZE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, Texture.SIZE, Texture.SIZE, textures.size());

    try {
        int layer = 0;
        for (Texture tex : textures.values()) {
            // Next few lines are just for loading the texture. They've been ruled out as the issue.
            PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(ImageHelper.asInputStream(tex.getImage()));
            ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight() * 4);
            decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
            buffer.flip();

            glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, layer, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 1,
                    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

            tex.setLayer(layer);

            layer++;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Failed to create/load texture array");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The code for creating the VAO/VBO:

```java
private static int prepareVbo(int handle, FloatBuffer vbo) {
    IntBuffer vaoHandle = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    glGenVertexArrays(vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle.get());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GraphicsMain.TEXTURE_REGISTRY.atlasHandle);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrIndex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttrIndex);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttrIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 12);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    vaoHandle.rewind();
    return vaoHandle.get();
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2DArray texArray;

varying vec3 texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture(texArray, texCoord);
}
```

(`texCoord` is working fine; it's being passed from the vertex shader correctly.)

I'm about out of ideas, so being still somewhat new to modern OpenGL, I'd like to know if there's anything glaringly wrong with my code.

Comment: What are your texture coordinates? Ensure that that the layer index is an integer, not a normalized `0`-`1` value.

Comment: "`texture2DArray`" That is not a legal GLSL 3.30 function. The function you use to sample from a texture array is called `texture`, just like the function you use to sample from textures of all kinds.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The xy-coordinates are either 0 or 1 depending on the vertex being rendered. The layer is stored as an `int` and passed directly from the accessor to the `FloatBuffer` provided as a VBO.

Comment: @NicolBolas Odd, it compiles fine. Regardless, I've replaced it with `texture` and I'll update the OP momentarily to reflect this.

Comment: @caseif: What do you mean by "The layer is stored as an `int` and passed directly from the accessor to the `FloatBuffer`"? Make sure proper floating point values are passed in there.

Comment: @derhass My understanding is that the z-index is passed as an integer index rather than a float as is the case with x and y. Is this not correct?

Comment: @caseif: Not really. A 2D array texture is sampled  by a `vec3` texcoord vector. A `vec3` is all floats. What is meant is that the layers are addressed by whole numbers at 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 and so on. If you put a real integer encoding into the buffer, the bit sequence will be interpreted as a `float`, and you will get a completely wrong value.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: the `int` is added to a `FloatBuffer`, meaning it is implicitly typecast to a `float` and the correct encoding is used.

Comment: @caseif: I'd hoped so, but your wording wasn't 100% clear to me, so I wanted to rule out that potential source for an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some considerations:

- you don't need any more to have power of two textures
- be sure that every layer has the same number of levels/mipmaps, as the wiki [says](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture)
- the first four `glTexParameteri` will affect what is bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` *at that moment*, so you better want to move them after `glBindTexture`
- how can you specify how many textures you want to create with `glGenTextures()`? If you have the possibility for a more specific method, please use it
- [`GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glPixelStorei.xhtml) if greater than 0, defines the number of pixels in a row. I suppose then `Texture.SIZE` is not really the texture size but the dimension on one side (128 in your case). Anyway you don't need to set that, you can skip it
- set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 4 only if your row lenght is a multiple of it. Most of time people set it to 1 before loading a texture to avoid any trouble and then set it back to 4 once done
- last argument of `glTexStorage3D` is expected to be the number of layers, I hope `textures.size()` better returns that rather than the size (128x128)
- `glActiveTexture` and `glBindTexture` inside `prepareVbo` are useless, they are not part of the vao
- don't use `varying` in glsl, it's deprecated, switch to a simple `in out`
- you may want to take inspiration from [this sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_420/Gl_420_texture_array.java)
- use sampler, they give you more flexibility
- use [Debug Output](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) if available, otherwise `glGetError()`, some silent errors may not be seen explicitely by the rendering output
- you called it `prepareVbo` but you do initialize in it both vao and vbo

Comment: I've verified all of these and updated the OP, but the textures still don't function. A couple notes: `glGenTextures()` (without args) implies 1 texture to be generated. `textures.size()` returns the number of individual textures in the texture `List`, which is also the correct layer count.

Comment: Solved - I'd forgotten to remove the `glBindTexture` call from `prepareVbo`. Omitting this causes the textures to work perfectly. Out of curiosity, why would calling this function break the program?

Comment: Glad you solved. The only logical reason I can think of is that somewhere after `prepareVbo` you are calling some function that will modify a parameter of the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`, that is `GraphicsMain.TEXTURE_REGISTRY.atlasHandle`. Ps: I added another couple of hints ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing samplers.